# How to incorporate FileName in Pig Latin Script using XMLLoader?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming

I am using XMLLoader to load XML in my pig latin script.And then parsing it with my UDF.
The problem is that i want to incorporate the input filename in my UDF.

Something like

fileName = (String)input.get(1);

Here is my Pig Latin code For reference

```
REGISTER contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar;
REGISTER TallyUDF.jar;
log = LOAD '/home/HadoopNaman1/pig/trunk/CompFetXML.xml' using  org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage..XMLLoader('ENVELOPE') as xml_record;
N = FOREACH log GENERATE FLATTEN(TallyUDF.ParseCompFet(xml_record)) as (key:CHARARRAY,value1:CHARARRAY,value2:CHARARRAY);
M = FILTER N by key is not null;
DUMP M;
```

I think i have to edit XMLLoader.java code.However, I am not able to think how to do that.

Comment: This answer might give you some idea how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9760836/1050422