# How to get the name of the file being executed by the mapper in Hadoop Map reduce framework in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

Currently I am using PIG language for writing Map Reduce program in Hadoop framework.

Could you please help me in finding the name of the file being executed by the mapper in Hadoop Map Reduce framework by using the language PIG.

Comment: Sorry, but I think someone needs to write a Pig script to understand what is being asked in this question. No offence.

Comment: Have you tried solutions listed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751480/how-can-i-incorporate-the-current-input-filename-into-my-pig-latin-script ?