# Load multiple files with PigLatin (Hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a hdfs file list of csv files with same format. I need to be able to `LOAD` them with pig together. Eg:

```
/path/to/files/2013/01-01/qwe123.csv
/path/to/files/2013/01-01/asd123.csv
/path/to/files/2013/01-01/zxc321.csv
/path/to/files/2013/01-02/ert435.csv
/path/to/files/2013/01-02/fgh987.csv
/path/to/files/2013/01-03/vbn764.csv
```

They can not be globed as their name is "random" hash and their directories might contain more csv files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7341236/2103450

Comment: So just separating with comma, ha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in other comments, you can do this by pre-processing the file. Suppose your HDFS file is called `file_list.txt`, then you can do the following:

```
pig -param flist=`hdfs dfs -cat file_list.txt | awk 'BEGIN{ORS="";}{if (NR == 1) print; else print ","$0;}'` script.pig
```

The `awk` code gets rid of the newline characters and uses commas to separate the file names.

In your script (called `script.pig` in my example), you should use parameter substitution to load the data:

```
data = LOAD '$flist';
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to escape the separator? Because my file names seem to contain commas :(

Answer (score 1):

You aren't restricted to globbing.  Use this:

`LOAD '/path/to/files/2013/01-{01/qwe123,01/asd123,01/zxc321,02/ert435,02/fgh987,03/vbn764}.csv';`

Comment: Parsing the file names would be kind if a burden, also I do not have control over the paths I get in the file. They might change.

Comment: Construct a string like `{path1,path2,path3}` and pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: @Veseliq run a shell script to ls the file names you're interested in and concat them to a string like winnie mentions above.